# PowerShell : Divide Files by Line in Faster Way

Tags: powershell

We're considering to divide huge file, over 25GB and to import into Redshift DWH.
So far, we can simply divide the file by 1000000 lines, but it took almost two hours to divide into 111 files.

```
$i=1; cat .\TRGET_FILE.csv -ReadCount 1000000 | % { $_ > TRGET_FILE_$i.csv;$i++ }
```

Also we'd like to escape the word '\' to '\\' in each files, so as not to prevent Redshift data load. But it consumes both of time and resources in this way.

Could you kindly let me know if you'll know any better solutions?
Thank you.

Comment: In addition to [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68354750/15339544) excellent answer, if you're looking for efficiency try to avoid pipelines and `ForEach-Object` \ `Where-Object`.

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon Many thanks for your another useful information. We'll sure to try ForEach-Object \ Where-Object:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat` is an alias for `Get-Content` which is notoriously slow at reading files. I also suspect that using redirection may not be the best way to write the target file either.

Let's try using some .Net classes and methods instead:

```
$bigfile = '.\TRGET_FILE.csv'
$outfile = '.\TRGET_FILE{0:d5}.csv'
$linecount = 1000000
$i = 0
$outstream = $null

foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($bigfile)) {
    if (($i % $linecount) -eq 0) {
        if ($null -ne $outstream) { $outstream.Close() }
        $outstream = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new(($outfile -f ($i/$linecount)))
    }

    $outstream.WriteLine($line.Replace('\', '\\'))

    $i++
}
$outstream.Close()
```

The `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines` method is very fast, and we can iterate over it quickly with a `foreach` loop, without reading every line from the file first.

Since each iteration of the loop processes a single line, we'll write it out to the target file. But we don't want to use something like `Out-File -Append` because it will reopen and close the file every time.

So instead, when we calculate that we've reached the number of lines (or on the first iteration), we can open a new file as a `[System.IO.File]::StreamWriter`,  and that way we have it open already, and can write out each line.

When we write the line, we also replace a single backslash `\` character with two backslashes.

When we reach the desired number of lines, we first check if the `$outstream` is `$null` (it will be `$null` the first time), and if it's not null, we close the stream (to close the output file), and then create a new one, with the new file name.

The output file name is templated to a 5 digit number via string templating.
`{0:d5}` -- `0` means the first item in the template, `d` is for a number, `5` tells it to ensure the number is at least 5 digits, so it will pad it with zeroes. That will help with file ordering.

Finally at the end of the loop, which will end before reaching the desired number of lines (the tail of the file), we close that last stream.

頑張ってね

Comment: @ briantist Wow, that's so perfect answer for me, briantist !! Not only the perfect script including replace logic  but also with the kind instructions. I'll give it try right away. Thank you so much and have a wonderful day :) どうもありがとう:)

Comment: @Sachiko I hope it is helpful, I did not test it so it might need some changes or fixes, but it might be a good starting point! 

Comment: Thank a lot again for your another comment. I tried your script and it worked perfectly, it reduced our operation time over 2 hrs to only 20 mins. Since we need to take care of our encoding, we use "[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("sjis")" for ReadLines, to avoid any garbled characters. But it's still fast :)  Many, many thanks for all of your considerations, briantist. Have a beautiful day!!

Comment: @Sachiko やった！I'm so happy it worked well! The use of ShiftJIS encoding instead of a Unicode system is a little surprising, but it's good to know it was an easy change. Are you writing ShiftJIS as well? Or is the target file different? Anyway, thanks for following up Sachiko, it's always nice to hear. 

Comment: We really appreciated all of your consideration, briantist. Yes, we sometimes need Shift-JIS for both of legacy and current system, to handle our Japanese characters. But you know, your wonderful script is exporting UTF-8 without Bom, it's required for our Redshift uploading. So, only we had to do was just to read contents in Shift-JIS, instead of UTF16, default encoding in PowerShell. You really saved our day!! 本当にありがとう:)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to limit the chunk size to 1m ~ 2m by reducing the readcount? some thing  like this:

```
$i = 1; $j = 1
Get-Content .\TRGET_FILE.csv -ReadCount 10000 | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_ | Add-Content -Path TRGET_FILE_$i.csv
        $j++
        if ($j -eq 100) { 
            j=1; i++ 
        } 
    }
```

if this works better you can apply the replacement like this:

```
$i = 1; $j = 1 
Get-Content .\TRGET_FILE.csv -ReadCount 10000 | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_.replace('\', '\\') | Add-Content -Path TRGET_FILE$i.csv
        $j++
        if ($j -eq 100) {
            j=1; i++
        }
    }
```

A lot of this depends the disk IO, so have a disk that is super fast on read and write block will help.

Comment: Your answer has typos in it and OP's code is definitely more efficient than this, recommending to use `Add-Content` which is generating more Disk I/O than before is not the correct answer.

Comment: My take on this is that there might be difference between set-content a 200m file  (essentially op is doing) vs add-content 2m x100 times, but that might be insignificant comparing to the 2hr problem statement. So problem may lay else where, like memory constrains. Essentially we need to benchmark this thing out.

Comment: @user6932954 Thanks a lot for your useful information. 'Add-Content' is very useful and I'll try it too:)

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon  Thank you so much for your other comment, Santiago.

Answer (score 0):

The linux shell command split is made to do this exact job.  It can split files by lines of any line count you wish.  See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html

```
split -l 1000000 -da 4 file_in file_out
```

Comment: Thank a lot again, Bill:) This time we need to do it on Windows, but I can try it at other time in Linux. Thanks for useful information always :)

Comment: But this was a Powershell question!